# requireJS defining a module based on browser support

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I am trying to define a view (module) based on fileReader support.  Depending on the support, different templates/modules are involved.  What's the best way to accomplish this?

My first thought was:

```
define([...],function(...){

   var reference;

   if
     require([...], function( something ){reference = something )
   else 
     require([...], function( something ){reference = something )

   // rest of module definition
})
```

But that obviously fails do to the asynchronous nature of it all.

Answer (score 0):

Your best way is to detect browser support in `require.config` section.

```
require.config({
    path: {
        myModule: myUtils.isBrowserSupportFileReader ? 'myModule/fileReader' : 'myModule/noFileReader'
    }
});
```

If later you will need to compile packages with `almond.js` you can create two packages for new and old browsers.